# Trigger on Notes (lightning)

Tags: apex, trigger, contentversion, contentnote

Requirement: If a note is added to either an account, contact, opportunity, task and event for particular record types and the current user is not an administrator and not a user mentioned in system label, add error!

Seems like a simple and fair enough requirement doesn't it? However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to acheive this. I have read on Salesforce SOAP API Developer Guide - 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm and in the url it says 'ContentNote is built on ContentVersion, and so it has many of the same usages.' so I figured perhaps a trigger on ContentVersion might do the trick but I was wrong.

I am wondering if someone could help me please? When I delete a note the below is not firing!

Could I write a trigger on Note object instead?

Below is my trigger, System Labels and helper class:

System Labels:
NL_Record_Type_Labels = 'Lead','NL Lead','Account','NL Account','Contact','NL Contact','Opportunity','NL Opportunity','Task','NL Task','Event','NL Event'

NL_Sales_Default_User = 0059EXXXXXXXXXX {user id of a user}

```
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (before delete) {
    if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isDelete){
        ContentNoteCustomClass.preventDeletion(trigger.old);
        System.debug('In ContentVersionTrigger');
    }            
}
```

**Helper Class**

```
public class ContentNoteCustomClass {
    public static void preventDeletion(list<ContentVersion> conVersion){
        Id UserAllowedToDelete = System.Label.NL_Sales_Default_User; 
        Set<id> conDoc = new Set<id>();
        Set<id> NL_Notes = new Set<id>();
        for(ContentVersion cv: conVersion){
            if(cv.filetype == 'SNOTE'){
                conDoc.add(cv.ContentDocumentId);
                System.debug('S Note added with content doc id '+cv.ContentDocumentId);
            }
        }
        List<ContentDocumentLink> conDocLink = [Select id, LinkedEntityId, LinkedEntity.RecordTypeId, ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where ContentDocumentId in: conDoc];
        System.debug('conDocLink '+conDocLink);

        Map<id,String> NLRecordTypes = new Map<id,String>();

        String[] objRecTypeArr = System.Label.NL_Record_Type_Labels.split(',');

        for(Integer i=1;i<objRecTypeArr.size();i+2){
            NLRecordTypes.put(getRecordTypeIdForObject(objRecTypeArr[i-1], objRecTypeArr[i]),objRecTypeArr[i]);
        }
        System.debug('NLRecordTypes map: '+NLRecordTypes);

        for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: conDocLink){
            if(NLRecordTypes.containsKey(cdl.LinkedEntity.RecordTypeId) && UserInfo.getUserId().substring(0,15) <> UserAllowedToDelete && UserInfo.getProfileId().substring(0,15) <> '00e20000000pwXc'){
                NL_Notes.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId);
                System.debug('Added to NL_Notes '+NL_Notes);
            }   
        }

        for(ContentVersion cv: conVersion){
            if(cv.filetype == 'SNOTE' && NL_Notes.contains(cv.ContentDocumentId)){
                System.debug('Will throw error');
                cv.addError('Only default sales user can delete notes');
            }
        }


    }

    private static Id getRecordTypeIdForObject(String objName, String recTypeName) {
    return ((SObject)Type.forName(objName).newInstance())
        .getSObjectType()
        .getDescribe()
        .getRecordTypeInfosByName()
        .get(recTypeName)
        .getRecordTypeId();
    }
}
```

Comment: See @CharlesT's suggestion of using a trigger on `ContentDocumentLink`.  I've used triggers on this and it's worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Object model reminder:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm

Notice that while it does use `ContentVersion` and `ContentDocumentLink` it does NOT use `ContentDocument`.

Also you might want to consider putting the trigger on `ContentDocumentLink` because otherwise you allow a possible scenario where a non-admin user unlinks the Note first from the record and then deletes it.

Finally I would advise against hard-coding any IDs into the Apex.