# Trigger on ContentDocumentLink is not firing

Tags: trigger, contentdocument

All, I am writing this trigger to prevent the deletion of attachment and notes for cases whose status is completed. But it's not getting fired. Please help.

```
trigger PreventDeletion on ContentDocumentLink (before delete) {
                Map<Id, Case> closedCasesMap = new Map<Id, Case>();
                for(Case cs: [Select Id from Case  where Status = 'Completed'  ]){
                    closedCasesMap.put(cs.Id, cs);
                }
                for(ContentDocumentLink a : Trigger.old) {
                    if(closedCasesMap.containsKey(a.LinkedEntityId)){
                        a.addError('Cant delete attachment for completed Case');
                    }
                }            
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working in LEX, the trigger won't fire on ContentDocumentLink.

[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312746&type=1&mode=1) is the article mentioning the same. Below is an excerpt from the article.

The following behavior applies to the deletion of a file attached to a record:

- In Classic, ContentDocument triggers do not fire, as Salesforce only
  deletes the associated ContentDocumentLink record, not the
  ContentDocument record.
- In Lightning Experience, both the ContentDocument and related ContentDocumentLink records are deleted, **and by design Salesforce only fires the trigger on ContentDocument, not the trigger on ContentDocumentLink.**

Comment: and also which object do we use to write trigger on Notes in salesforce ?

Comment: [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215727/trigger-on-notes-lightning) should help you. It is recommended to use ContentDocumentLink

Answer (score 0):

// You  trigger needs to be on Attachment object

// You can create Trigger on Attachment object from Developer console

```
trigger AttachmentTrigger on Attachment(before delete) {
    Set < Id > setCaseIds = new Set < Id > ();
    for (Attachment att: Trigger.old) {
        String parentObjId = att.ParentId;
        //500 is the starting sting in ID for all Cases
        if (parentObjId.startsWith('500')) {
            setCaseIds.add(att.ParentId);
        }
    }
    if (!setCaseIds.IsEmpty()) {
            // Fetching all cases where  status is Completed
            Map < Id, Case > MapIdToCase = new Map < Id, Case > ([Select Id from Case where Status = 'Completed']);
            if (!MapIdToCase.IsEmpty())
                for (Attachment att1: Trigger.old) {
                    if (MapIdToCase.ContainsKey(att1.ParentId)) {
                        att1.addError('Cant delete attachment for completed Case');
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE; pro tip: Instead of `parentObjId.startsWith('500')`, use `parentObjId.getSobjectType() == Case.SObjectType)` - more expressive